# AspNetCore.Reporting not working on linux machine?

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting-services, aws-lambda, rdlc, aws-serverless

I am working with report in ASP.Net Core using AspNetCore.Reporting to create report. When I executed the report in windows machine it work fine. However if i executed on linux machine I got this error.

`An error occurred during local report processing.;The definition of the report '/var/task/Reports/Report.rdlc' is invalid. An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies.`

Note: I deploy the application using serverless in AWS and aspnetcore as the runtime.

Can anyone help to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I use Itext/Itextsharp as alternative to create PDF. The functionality to create PDF is open source

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work on linux and that package hasn't received an update since 2018.

There are other alternatives such as syncfusion pdf (paid) or Rotativa that creates pdf files from MVC views, rotativa uses wkhtmltopdf (open source and cross-platform).